# How to find the % of the blocked Client/Server Application Attacks

Tags: security, checkpoint

I'm trying to do a small work in comparing some brands of security appliances such as Fortinet and Checkpoint.

I already found some important info about both Checkpoint https://www.checkpoint.com/downloads/product-related/comparison-chart/appliance-comparison-chart.pdf and Fortinet https://www.fortinet.com/content/dam/fortinet/assets/data-sheets/Fortinet_Product_Matrix.pdf

But after doing a quick search on the internet, i found that there is another relevant comparison i can do, which is the % of the blocked Client/Server Application Attacks that each brand product mitigate. ( http://www.tomsitpro.com/articles/next-generation-firewall-vendors,2-847-2.html )

My question is: Is there any website where i can find more information about this topic? Or is there any way in which i can calculate it?

Thanks for the help,
Luís

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another source that you can use is the NSS Labs yearly independent [testing report](https://www.nsslabs.com/demand/ngfw-download-reports/) for next generation firewall vendors (2017 press-release [here](https://www.nsslabs.com/company/news/press-releases/nss-labs-announces-2017-next-generation-firewall-group-test-results/)).